# popup with jquery ui in asp.net mvc2

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I work on a project using ASP.NET MVC 2 (C#). I use the jQueryUI JavaScript library to show a popup window to list the different themes in my database. In my view I use the following code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {


                              $("#dialog").dialog("close");



            },
            "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });
    $("#show-dialog").button().click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});  
</script>  


<div id="dialog" title="choisir le thème "  > 

<% using (Html.BeginForm())
{ %> 
    <p> <span style="color: #0000FF"><strong><em>Titre du document : 
    <%=Html.TextBox("Title")  %></em></strong></span>  </p>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 184px">Liste des thèmes </th><th>&nbsp;</th>   
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="width: 184px; height: 131px">
                    <%= Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedThème, Model.ThèmeList, new { size = "6" })%> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>        
    </table>     
     <% } %>   
</div>

<span id="show-dialog">thème</span>   
<%=Html.TextBox("thème")%>
```

A popup window opens and the list of themes is shown, but when I select a theme the popup should close and the selected theme should be shown in a text box control.
help me please

---

so my code will :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () { $("#thème").val($("#SelectedTheme").val());
                                  $(this).dialog("close"); },
            "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });
    $("#show-dialog").button().click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});


$('#SelectedTheme').change(function () {
    //do whatever you want to do here.
    $("#thème").val($("#SelectedTheme").val());
    $('#dialog').dialog('close');

});

</script>  




<div id="dialog" title="choisir le thème "  > 

 <% using (Html.BeginForm())
 { %> 

  <select id="SelectedTheme" multiple="multiple" name="SelectedTheme">
    <option>item1-in-ThemeList</option>
     <option>item2-in-ThemeList</option>
   </select>


 <% } %>   
 </div>  

 <fieldset>

 <span id="show-dialog">thème</span>   <%=Html.TextBox("thème")%> 
 </fieldset>
```

but when i select a item the popup not close and the value of my text box not change.
help me !!!

Answer (score 0):

Following line

```
<%= Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedTheme, Model.ThemeList, new { size = "6" })%>
```

will produce html like this:

```
<select id="SelectedTheme" multiple="multiple" name="SelectedTheme">
<option>item1-in-ThemeList</option>
<option>item2-in-ThemeList</option>
....
</select>
```

So you would know what to do with following jquery pattern:

```
$('#SelectedTheme').live('change', function() 
{
    //do whatever you want to do here.
    $("#theme").val($("#SelectedTheme").val()); 
    $('#dialog').dialog('close');

});
```

Comment: the same problem when i selected the item the popup doesn't close please help me

Comment: thank a looootttt, when i selected a item the popup close but the item don't save in the textbox . the code of my textbox is <%=Html.TextBox("sometextbox")%>.I think the mistake is here.please help me.

Comment: I didn't previously see your textbox in your code so I gave arbitrary name. My fault. I believe you should change it to `<%=Html.TextBox("theme")%>` and javascript accordingly to make it whole thing work.

Comment: Are you using 'thème' instead of 'theme' by any chance? Otherwise, I can't find any reason why it does not work. Can you make it available in website or jfiddle? Or you might have to debug it with firebug in firefox or something like that.